# Execute a custom function on 'user register' or 'login'

Tags: 8, hooks, console

I am new to Drupal. I want to execute my custom function every time when user registers or logins to my site. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the following hooks in your module.

1. [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/8.2.x)
2. [hook_user_register](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/8.2.x) (In D7 we had `user_insert` hook.)

**Examples:**

User Login Hook:

```
function mymodule_user_login($account){

   //your code here
}
```

User Register Hook:

```
function mymodule_user_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity){

   //your code here

}
```

Comment: Thanq @esafwan . Where i need to place this code. In theme file or what ?

Comment: @Mithun You have put this in a module. What does the custom function do? You might be able to use rules module instead for some use cases.

Comment: How can i get form values like first name, last name, email and password in mymodule_user_insert

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for user login/register.